# microsoft word email attachment gets blocked

Tags: microsoft-word, email, attachments

Does anybody knows why the microsoft word email attachments gets blocked?

If I received 2 attachments:

1. a pdf document and
2. a .doc document,

just the .doc document gets blocked, I download to any folder and look at the properties and appears this button "unblock", when I click on that button now I can see the document.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/4pom2xd3f/]

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, [Blocked attachments in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-IN/article/Blocked-attachments-in-Outlook-434752e1-02d3-4e90-9124-8b81e49a8519#__toc273273751), this behavior intentional to protect your computer from harm.

> To help protect your computer, Outlook doesn’t allow you to receive
>   files of certain types (such as .exe files) as attachments, because of
>   their potential for introducing a virus into your computer. By
>   default, Outlook blocks these files.

Why are Word documents blocked? Somehow the `.doc` extension was added as a blocked file type.